# items doesnt stick to bottom react nativr

Tags: react-native

im trying to make a to-do list in react native and im trying to make the input and plus bar stick to the bottom and make it go up when i open the keyboard. when i use padding the bar sticks to bottom but i want to use flexbox to make it compatible with all phones. can someone help make stick it to bottom and make it go up with keyboard

task.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput,KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const AddTask = () => {
    const handleAddTask = () => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
        setTask(null);
      }



  return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style ={styles.inputbuttons}
    >
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Write a task'}  />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
        <View style = {styles.plus}>
            <Text>+</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 60,
    width:320,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius:20,
    
    

  },
  inputbuttons:{
    
        
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
},
 plus:{
    width:60,
    height:60,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'black',
    textAlign:'right',
    borderRadius:'15',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize:30
 }
});

export default AddTask;
```

app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button, Alert,Input } from 'react-native';
import Task from './components/Task';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style = {styles.taskWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Today's Tasks</Text>
        
      </View>

      <View style={styles.tasks}>
        <Task></Task>
        <Task></Task>
        
      </View>

      <View>
        <AddTask></AddTask>
      </View>
    </View>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',

  },
  taskWrapper:{
      paddingTop:80,
      paddingHorizontal:20
  },
  header:{
    fontSize:24,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  tasks:{
    
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use KeyboardAvoidingView in your app component so that whenever keyboard gets activated then the component of App gets pushed.